# Trigger an action when cell in static UITableView is tapped [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, iboutlet

I have eight, different static cells in a tableview. I am trying to perform different actions with six of the cells. Two of them open an alert view, two open safari, one clears a cache, and the last one opens a share popover. Previously, they all worked with UIButtons and IBActions. But since setting up a static tableview, I am running into issues.

I'm trying to link up the individual cells to their own actions and I can't seem to do that with outlets. How might I do this?

Thank you.

**Swift 3**

Table View code:

```
import UIKit

class AltSettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var copyrightInfo: UITableViewCell!

@IBOutlet weak var shareApp: UITableViewCell!

@IBOutlet weak var rateApp: UITableViewCell!

@IBOutlet weak var clearCache: UITableViewCell!

@IBOutlet weak var purchasePhotos: UITableViewCell!

@IBOutlet weak var helpFeedback: UITableViewCell!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.minimum(35, 35)
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you overridden `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)`? It should let you know when a cell is tapped and then you can use `indexPath` to determine which cell it was.

Edit: documentation for [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) and [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsindexpath).

Example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        // do stuff
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have not added `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)`. Once I add that, how would I use indexPath to determine which cell is tapped? Thanks.

Comment: `indexPath` has properties `row` and `section`. It looks like you only have one section in your table (unless there's part of the setup that's missing), so the first cell would be at `indexPath.row == 0`, the second is `indexPath.row == 1`, and so on.

Comment: Great, thanks. Getting an error with ` override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath.row = 7) {` with 'row' is not a member of type of 'IndexPath'. Where should the `indexpath.row == 1` go? Thank you very much.

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thank you. Have all the code in place and since I have eight cells in the table, I put in `indexPath.row == 7` because I want to add an action to the seventh cell. Nothing is happening when I tap the seventh cell. Could it be because it's a static, grouped table?

Comment: It should still work. Is the tableView's delegate set to AltSettingsTableViewController? If you set a breakpoint on the first line of that method, does the method get called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131379/discussion-between-samantha-and-miles).